# DOM manipulation , function, promises and asyn await

Tags: function, promise, appendchild, removechild, getelementsbytagname

The code should return a function that finds all elements in the DOM with the tagname "todo-item". Every one of these elements should then be removed from its current parent node and appended to the body element of the current document. The function should return a Promise that resolves once all of the elements were successfully added to the body element.

```
//a function that finds all elements in the DOM with the tagname „todo-item“.
 function getToDoElement() {
  //this captures every element with the tag name "todo-item" and stores it in a variable
  //This method create an array of the specified element in the DOM
  let toDoTag = document.getElementsByTagName("todo-item");

  //these elements should then be removed from its current parent node andd stored in a variable.
  /*while (toDoTag.firstChild) {
    toDoTag.removeChild(toDoTag.firstChild);
} */
  let removeToDoItem = document.body.removeChild(toDoTag);

  //append to the body element of the current document.
  //assuming the current document is element.
  let newDoc = document.getElementsByTagName("body");

  //append the previous child element to the new parent
  document.newDoc.appendChild(removeToDoItem);

  //The function should return a Promise that resolves once all of the elements were successfully added to the body element.
  return new Promise ( (resolve) =>{
   resolve(document.newDoc.appendChild(removeToDoItem)); 

  } )

}
```

Comment: What is this code for? The structure and comments make it look like a University / School assignment of some sort

Comment: There is no reason to use promises here because all of this code is synchronous.  You can just return a result directly.

Comment: Yes they synchronous, but then it should return a pro.ise that resolves when the body as been successfully appended? Are the other code right?